# cURL a url with a webcal protocol

Tags: php, facebook, curl, icalendar

I'm trying to curl a url that begins with a webcal protocol using php:

webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=622488169

cURL doesn't recognize the webcal protocol.  In the course of my research I've read that changing the protocol in the url to http should work, however, Facebook seems to have disallowed access to the file when the protocol is http.  So, I was wondering if there is a way to tell cURL to treat a webcal protocol like it would a http protocol.  I don't have access to the php installation or php.ini so I need to do it in the script.

Here's what I have, not that the code is really necessary here, it's just a basic curl setup:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=622488169',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    );

curl_setopt_array($ch,$options); 

if($content = curl_exec ($ch)){
    echo $content;
} else {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

But it seems to work with **https**, just replace webcal with https.

Now Facebook events URL has an additional parameter 'key' I dont know how long the URL is valid...

Sorry for my bad english

Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

`webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=622488169` isn't working for me in iCal. Are you sure it's not a problem with restricted access?

Comment: That could be a problem too.  But the first problem is that I get this error using curl: Unsupported protocol: webcal  The url works when pasting it into the address bar of Firefox.